# how to see error logs in django view when not returning a view

Tags: django, django-views, django-errors

I am doing an ajax post to a django view.  Since I am not returning a page but data to my ajax call back, I do not get a stack trace.  How do I print my errors in the view?

The error is happening when I do a save if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```